# create automatic relationship in various SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, t-sql, postgresql

i have many database  that  foreign-key(informal) field name and primary-key fieldname are same for sample visible in following code.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
   CustomerId int PRIMARY,
   CustomerName varchar(200),
...
)
CREATE TABLE Invoice(
      InvoiceID int PRIMARY KEY,
      InvoiceType int ,
      CustomerID int)
CREATE TABLE InvoiceDet(
      InvoiceDetId int PRIMARY KEY,
      InvoiceId int ...)
```

i want a program(or a script) that read my tables ,columns and create foreign key references.samples of should be produced relationship:   `Customer.CustomerId<=>Invoice.CustomerID` and 
`InvoiceDet.InvoiceId<=>Invoice.InvoiceId`

Comment: Are we playing dbms roulette? Pick one...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *automatic relationship*? I don't understand that term

Comment: You want a program that reads your tables and creates foreign key references automatically?

Comment: yes @Catcall . i want a program(or a script) that read my tables ,columns and create  foreign key references.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *huge* task to create such automated scripts, especially for all databases you've mentioned. You should consider hiring a couple of good DBAs with perl/python knowledge to do the thing for you.

With minimal amount of checks (number of columns in the keys and types of the columns are not cross checked), the following might be a [concept proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/cd008/2) for PostgreSQL:

```
WITH colnames(oid,colnum,colname) AS (
    SELECT a.attrelid AS oid, a.attnum AS colnum, a.attname AS colname
      FROM pg_attribute a WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped),
pkcols(oid,colnum) AS (
    SELECT c.conrelid AS oid, unnest(c.conkey)
      FROM pg_constraint c
     WHERE contype = 'p'),
pks(oid,colnum,colname) AS (
    SELECT pkc.oid, pkc.colnum, cn.colname
      FROM pkcols pkc
      JOIN colnames cn ON pkc.oid = cn.oid AND pkc.colnum = cn.colnum),
pktabs AS (
    SELECT t.oid AS oid, n.nspname AS sname, t.relname AS tname,
           pks.colnum AS colnum, pks.colname AS colname
      FROM pg_class t
      JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
      JOIN pks ON pks.oid = t.oid
     WHERE t.relkind = 'r'),
coltabs AS (
    SELECT t.oid AS oid, n.nspname AS sname, t.relname AS tname,
           cn.colnum AS colnum, cn.colname AS colname
      FROM pg_class t
      JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
      JOIN colnames cn ON cn.oid = t.oid
     WHERE t.relkind = 'r')
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||quote_ident(ct.sname)||'.'||quote_ident(ct.tname)||
       ' ADD FOREIGN KEY ('||string_agg(quote_ident(pk.colname),',')||
       ') REFERENCES '||
       quote_ident(pk.sname)||'.'||quote_ident(pk.tname)||' ('||
       string_agg(quote_ident(pk.colname),',')||');'
  FROM pktabs pk
  JOIN coltabs ct ON pk.oid != ct.oid AND pk.colname = ct.colname
 GROUP BY pk.sname,pk.tname,ct.sname,ct.tname;
```